# Extracting contents of ConnectionStrings in web.config in Silverlight Business application

Tags: .net, sql-server, silverlight-4.0, webconfigurationmanager

I am trying to read dataSource ad Catalog from `<connectionStrings>` in web.config in Silverlight business project. Unfortunately  when I used `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`, I could not read connection string the has

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/MainDatabase.Main.csdl|res://*/MainDatabase.Main.ssdl|......."
```

where as it work for

```
connectionString="Data Source=My-PC\SQL_2008;Initial Catalog =....
```

I could get them using "Split" however, I don't like that solution. Is there any way to get my requirements?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first connection string (that isn't working) is an Entity Framework connection string - it isn't in a format the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` can understand.  However, `EntityConnectionStringBuilder` *will* understand that, and it has a property called `ProviderConnectionString`.  This property will have the actual SQL connection string in it, which you can pass to a `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` as in your second example.